# Trying to .replace() Without Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have some lines of HTML code that are like this:

```
<li><a href="#" class="lstItem">Testing jQuery [First Bracket]</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="lstItem">Loving jQuery [Second one]</a></li>
```

I'm trying to replace what's inside the bracket with nothing `onLoad`, like this:

```
var item = $(".lstItem").text();
var match = item.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
item = item.replace(match[0], "");
```

But nothing changes. What's wrong and how to correct this?

---

After using [jimbojw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199163/jimbojw)'s suggestion I'm getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined` at this particular line:

```
oldtext = $item.text,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do the job for you:
you are splitting your code in too much lines, also your need to run replace for each individual element separately.

```
$(".lstItem").each(function() {
   $(this).html(
       $(this).html().replace(/\[(.*)\]/, "")
   );
});
```

see your example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKn3Q/7/

Comment: Technically speaking, this doesn't do the same thing as OP's posted queston for two reasons.  First, in your code, only the content between the square brackets will be emptied, whereas in the original, the first instance of whatever was in the square brackets would be emptied.  It's a safe bet that what you're doing is really what he wants to achieve though, so in that sense, it's better.  Secondly, you're setting and modifying the HTML, as opposed to the text.  It's not clear which is closer to the actual requirements (unbeknownst to us).

Answer (score 8):

`item` is a variable containing a string, not a pointer to the literal text.  If you want to change the text, you have to set it again, vis a vis `$(".listItem").text(item)`

#### edit - predicting next problem

The next problem you're going to have is that all the text gets set to the same thing.  So what you *really* want to do is probably something like this:

```
$(".lstItem")
  .each(function(index, item) {

    var
      $item = $(item),
      oldtext = $item.text(),
      match = oldtext.match(/\[(.*?)\]/),
      newtext = oldtext.replace(match[0], '');

    $item.text(newtext);

  });
```

Comment: Got this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined` at the line 6 of your code

Comment: Sorry, I had named the text variable 'text', then switched it to 'oldtext' and forgot some references.  It's now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Along with jimbojw's answer `$(".lstItem").text()` will retrieve all the text inside of your `<a/>` elements.  One way to handle this would be to pass a `function(i,t){}` into the `.text()` method.

```
$(".lstItem").text(function(i, text){
    var match = text.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
    return text.replace(match[0], "");    
});
```

**[Simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/eJZ3E/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

also your regex could be simpler.

```
var item = $(".lstItem").text();
var match = /\[(.*?)\]/;
$(".listItem").text(item.replace(match,""));
```